# Apache - 404 Not Found

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, virtualhost, ubuntu-16.04

Good Afternoon,

I'm elaborating a project and I've instaled php,mysql, apache2 in a virtualbox with ubuntu16.04. I'm working locally and I've instaled laravel 5.3, I have an API running and created a new virtual host and placed the `DocumentRoot my_folder/public` and `ServerName name_virtual_host`. Then I went to my host files and placed a new line: `127.0.0.1 name_virtual_host`. When I place on my browser http://name_virtual_host, the laravel page appears like it is supposed, but when I type in http://name_virtual_host/api, it gives back:

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /api was not found on this server.
>
> Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at name_virtual_host Port 80 it used to
>   appear JSON.

my virtual Host:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName name_virtual_host
        DocumentRoot /var/www/my_folder/public
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

if inside my folder I write the comand

> php artisan serve

and put in URL:

> name_virtual_host:8000/api

, this works.

How can I solve this?
I think that the solution is creating the file .htaccess, but what should I put inside this file(.htaccess)?

Thanks.

Comment: This answer from Rishav worked for me. [How to run an php application without installing xampp on client system?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57870711/7519779)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel [should come with a `public/.htaccess` file](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/v5.3.16/public/.htaccess) which redirects all requests to `index.php` (the `RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]` part).

If you don't have this file, add it. If you already have this file, make sure `mod_rewrite` is enabled on your apache server (and restart it).

Without it, Apache will look for a file named `api` in your `DocumentRoot` when you ask for `/api`. The request must be sent to `index.php`, from the [laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/structure#the-public-directory):

> The public directory contains the index.php file, which is the entry point for **all requests** entering your application.

Comment: Thank you very much, missing the enabled mod_rewrite. Thank you